# How to solve "Exception: you need a C compiler to build uWSGI" on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: python-2.7, gcc, pip, ubuntu-18.04, uwsgi

i am trying to install `"uWSGI==2.0.4"` by `"pip install uWSGI==2.0.4"`, i have already installed `gcc 7.5.0` and build-essentials etc. still it shows

following errors:

```
conf = uc.uConf(get_profile())
    File "uwsgiconfig.py", line 682, in __init__
      raise Exception("you need a C compiler to build uWSGI")
  Exception: you need a C compiler to build uWSGI
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for uWSGI
```

OS :  Ubuntu-18.04

Python version : python2.7

How can i solve these errors?

Comment: Did you install gcc BEFORE uwsgi?

Answer (score 1):

Please try uWSGI with different version

try to install below version

uWSGI==2.0.17  by pip install uwsgi==2.0.17

It is working for me